# Why does the Symbol stringification operation appear to work with only single argument strings?

Tags: symbolic

I'm trying to label my symbolic object's using `Symbol`

Works as expected

```
Symbol["M" <> ToString[5]]
```

Output

```
M5
```

When I try do two variable indexing I get a result that doesn't work

```
Symbol[StringJoin["M", ToString[5], "_", ToString[12]]]
Symbol["M" <> ToString[5] <> "_" <> ToString[12]]
```

Output

```
Symbol["M5_12"]
Symbol["M5_12"]
```

So, the input to all three cases appears to be strings:

```
Head @ ("M" <> ToString[5])
Head @ (StringJoin["M", ToString[5], "_", ToString[12]])
Head @ ("M" <> ToString[5] <> "_" <> ToString[12])
```

Output

```
String      
String      
String
```

I'm confused.

Why does `Symbol` appear to have different output for the same class of input?

Comment: Well, darn, ain't it hard to find an explicit definition of a valid symbol name.  The documentation for `Symbol` may be as close as one can get: "The string `"name"` in `Symbol["name"]` must be an appropriate name for a symbol. It can contain any letters, letter-like forms, or digits, but cannot start with a digit." The clue is "letter-like form"; and an underscore is not a letter-like form but stands for `Blank[]`.  Other syntactic marks (`+`, `:`, `=`, etc.) are also not letter-like forms.

Comment: Better user experience would trigger an explicit error.

Comment: I get an error when I execute `Symbol["M5_12"]`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rPj7i.png

Comment: The error message from this input very clearly states that that this is not a valid symbol name.  I do not understand what your confusion is.

Comment: I don't see that error. Pehraps my version is different. I'll check when I get home.

Comment: Sometimes my errors get shunted to the Messages window, instead of being printed in the notebook.  (They should be printed to the `$Messages` output stream.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the variable names were invalid on the case of the underscore:

For example, when I change the naming function to the following I get the expected output:

```
Symbol[StringJoin["M", ToString[5], "x", ToString[12]]]
```

Comment: _ or [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) cannot appear in a variable name since it is a pattern object that can stand for any Wolfram Language expression.